# Не ставится задний фон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, background, path

Начал работать вчера, толком ничего не умею, но основные понятия понимаю.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не ставится бэкграунд:

```css
body {
  background: url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить что путь к файлу не правильный.

Comment: Попробуй отдельно поставить через `background-image`. Загляни в консоль во вкладку Network, скачивает ли браузер картинку или возвращает ошибку 404.

Comment: путь правильный,я уверен в этом

Comment: Почему новички так любят вставлять скриншоты вместо текста? Ведь скопипастить код намного проще, чем вставить скриншот (сделать, обрезать/сохранить, прицепить).

Comment: @L.F.C. Так в том то и дело, что вставить текст проще и быстрее, чем картинку, но вставляют картинку.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @L.F.C. Вставил картинку,чтобы понятнее было,я же не знал какие у вас тут "заповеди"

Comment: @Даниил чтоб знать, надо читать [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) (в которой все написано) на новом ресурсе, которым хотите пользоваться, так на любом адекватном сайте. Уже будете знать, на будущее )

Comment: Пусть к картинки не верный.

Comment: он правильный,я не раз проверял

Comment: Привел вопрос в соответствие к требованиям сайта (выделил проблему)

Comment: Путь у вас правильный. У вас где-то синтаксическая ошибка. Проверьте свой код.

Comment: В представленном тобой коде синтаксических ошибок нет, можешь показать файловую структуру. Ну и попробуй зайти в инспектор и посмотри какие стили применяются к нужному тебе блоку, возможно они где-то переопределются потом.

Answer (score 0):

С синтаксисом все в порядке, однозначно проблема в пути или картинке

```css
body {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150") no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Тут смысла отвечать нет, так как тут синтаксическая ошибка. В комментариях автору ответили. Есть для таких вопросов, пункт тревоги для закрытия вопроса.